# How can I extract information from a HTML code using Python + Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've to obtain the options that appear in this code and then put all of them into an array for later show these options in a GUI, but I don't know how to do this.

```
<select name="flt_technology" id="flt_technology" size="8" tabindex="1" multiple="" onchange="onChangeMessage('block','TechnicalReports');">
    <option value="3303">Aeroelastic Stability</option>
    <option value="3305">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aeroelastic Model</option>             
    <option value="3304">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aeroelastic Stability Criteria</option>
    <option value="3308">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aeroservoelastic Analysis</option>
    <option value="3306">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Control Surfaces Reversal/Effectiveness</option>
    <option value="3311">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Flutter Flight Test</option>
    <option value="3307">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Flutter</option>
    <option value="3309">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Flutter: Failure Conditions</option>
    <option value="3310">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ground Vibration Test</option>
    <option value="3710">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Qualification Equipment Test</option>
    <option value="3588">Weight and Balance</option>
    <option value="3589">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Center of Gravity Limits</option>
    <option value="3590">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leveling Means</option>
    <option value="3591">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loads Distribution - Weight X Cg Envelope Definition</option>
    <option value="3592">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Weight Limits</option>
</select>
```

Comment: did you try any tutorial ?

Comment: I'm new using selenium and I tried some methods but all of them had failed. Have you got an indication?

Comment: hava a look at beautifulsoup 4, it's a extention for scraping html

Comment: in question show code which you try to use and error message which you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *list* and *print* the text within the **options** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#flt_technology[name='flt_technology']"))))
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#flt_technology[name='flt_technology'] option")))])
  #or
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in select.options])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='flt_technology' and @name='flt_technology']"))))
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='flt_technology' and @name='flt_technology']//option")))])
  #or
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in select.options])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
  ```

Answer (score 0):

With `<select>` tag use `Select` class

```
element = self.find_element_by_id('flt_technology')
select = Select(element)
options = select.options
```

This will return a list of the `<option>` `WebElements`

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.the_website_you_want_to_scrape.com')
select_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('flt_technology')
options = [x for x in select_elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
```

And if you need the values of the options:

```
for element in options:
    print(element.get_attribute("value"))
```